# HTML Icons pack?

Tags: html, icons

Started learning html and css recently. I have googled around for a while and I cant seem to pick
what I want. I am looking for something like a pack that includes icons.  A standard pack.
I saw the Jquery UI icons and the bootstrap ones. Whats the best pack of icons to choose and how
do I use them? Also, what are they called? Favicons? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is very popular glyph icons set. You can use it.
http://fontello.com/

Answer (score 0):

Vector Font Icons?  Icon fonts?

Here's a very popular package that I personally enjoy using.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Here's another very popular one as well.

http://icomoon.io/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, I had no idea what they were called and this is perfect!

Comment: @user3728587 , no problem, enjoy!